# W11 context menu: moving "Create a shortcut" to primary context menu

Tags: windows-11, context-menu

I often need to create shortcuts, so how do I move "Create a shortcut" to the primary context menu and ideally make it show up as an icon alongside Cut, Copy, Paste etc there with Windows 11? (it's currently inside Show More Options) Thanks in advance!